# Why is the gsmSignalStrength always 0 in a Huawei phone? This is not the case for other phones

Tags: android, signal-strength

I have an app which shows the current signal strength, in many phones it is working, but when I test it on a Huawei phone, it is always 0, at the same time the signal bars are full in that huawei phone. what is the problem? is it related to android version? is it related to permissions? i have this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am using the correct way to get the Signal Strength but it is always 0 ASU.

Answer (score 1):

It's not always zero. The way you are getting the signal strength is wrong.
In some of the phones, it could be zero may be the removal of api.

Just try this code if it works for you.

```
     String gsmSignalStrength=null;
     String ssignal = asu.toString();
     String[] parts = ssignal.split(" ");
     int currentStrength = asu.getGsmSignalStrength();
                        if (currentStrength <= 0) {
                            gsmSignalStrength= String
                                    .valueOf(Integer.parseInt(parts[3]));
                        } else {
                            gsmSignalStrength= String.valueOf(-113 + 2 * asu.getGsmSignalStrength());
                        }
     Log.d(TAG,"Signal Strength : "+gsmSignalStrength);
```

This will works only for **GSM** ;

The parts array elements are described as

```
   parts[1] = GsmSignalStrength
   parts[3] = CDMADBM
   parts[8] = LteSignalStrength
   parts[9] = LteRsrp
   parts[10] = LteRsrq
   parts[13] = gsm|lte
```

So you can put some condition to extract value from this array.

Comment: Hi! I have been trying the same thing myself. Sometimes the GsmSignalStrength is 0 and sometimes it is not. Do you have any idea why? I noticed that the two fields "mWcdmaEcio" is always 255 and the field "mWcdmaRscp" is always 0 when the signal strength is not 0.

Comment: They have modified the signal strength API. Better to read `toString()` method of signal strength listener.

Comment: Nice answer Madhukar, It is helped me a lot.